# Multiple y-axes using Chart JS with data as a dictionary

Tags: javascript, chart.js, yaxis

I'm using Flask and the library Chart JS to do graph visualization. However, I need to be able to use multiple y-axes (2 for the moment) and I can't figure out a way to make things work. I've already done it with data as lists but now that I am using dictionary-like data it seems to not fit anymore.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js" integrity="sha512-UXumZrZNiOwnTcZSHLOfcTs0aos2MzBWHXOHOuB0J/R44QB0dwY5JgfbvljXcklVf65Gc4El6RjZ+lnwd2az2g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/1.2.1/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js" integrity="sha512-klQv6lz2YR+MecyFYMFRuU2eAl8IPRo6zHnsc9n142TJuJHS8CG0ix4Oq9na9ceeg1u5EkBfZsFcV3U7J51iew==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-R/QOHLpV1Ggq22vfDAWYOaMd5RopHrJNMxi8/lJu8Oihwi4Ho4BRFeiMiCefn9rasajKjnx9/fTQ/xkWnkDACg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@2.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div  class="chart-container">
    <canvas  id="myChart_0">
        <p> Fallback of a Graph </p>
    </canvas>
</div>
<script>  
    const dataset_0 = [{
                        data: [{x:new Date('2022-10-21T00:00:00'),y:1.0},{x:new Date('2022-12-16T00:00:00'),y:2.0},{x:new Date('2023-01-20T00:00:00'),y:2.0}],
                                barThickness: 3.0 ,
                                backgroundColor: "blue" ,
                                pointRadius: 0.0 ,
                                type: "line" ,
                yAxisID:'y',
                                borderColor: "blue" ,
                                label: "Graphs" ,
                                borderWidth: 0.0 ,
                datalabels: {color: '#FFCE56'},
                            },
    {
                        data: [{x:new Date('2022-10-21T00:00:00'),z:17.6},{x:new Date('2022-12-16T00:00:00'),z:16.9},{x:new Date('2023-01-20T00:00:00'),z:15.8}],
                                barThickness: 0.0 ,
                                backgroundColor: "red" ,
                                pointRadius: 0.0 ,
                                type: "bar" ,
                                borderColor: "red" ,
                yAxisID:'z',
                                label: "Graph" ,
                                borderWidth: 1.0 ,
                            },
    
    ];
    const data_0 = {
        datasets : dataset_0
    };
    
    const config_0 = {
    data: data_0,
    options: {
        animations:false,
        responsive: true,
        interaction: {
        },
        stacked: false,
        plugins: {
            title: {display: true, text: "None"},
            legend: { labels: { filter: function(item, chart) { return item.text; }, boxHeight : 4, boxWidth: 20}, display: true },
    },
        scales: {
        y: {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            borderWidth : 0.001,
            offset: true,
            grid :{
            display:true
            },
        },
        z: {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            borderWidth : 0.001,
            offset: true,
            grid :{
            display:true
            },
        },
        x1: {
            type: "time",
            display: true,
            offset: true,
            grid :{
            display:false
            },
        },
        },
    },
    };
    const myChart_0 = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart_0'), config_0);
 
</script>
```

I am hoping to get one graph with its scale on the right and the other on the left, so they can get their own scale because now the data is just on the same scale and it renders badly (with that current setup, I can't even see the line chart anymore).

I was wondering whether that difficulty was coming from the fact that the dictionary-like input makes you give both the labels and data at the same time or not.

If anyone knows how to deal with that issue, plz let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your object for your second dataset you define your object with a x and z key. Chart.js looks for an x and y key by default. If you want to change this and make chart.js look for different keys you need to configure that in the dataset like so:

```js
{
  data: [{x:new Date('2022-10-21T00:00:00'),z:17.6},{x:new Date('2022-12-16T00:00:00'),z:16.9},{x:new Date('2023-01-20T00:00:00'),z:15.8}],
  parsing: {
    yAxisKey: 'z'
  }
}
```

Or you can change the key to `y` and that will also solve your issue

Comment: when i add parsing like you said to, i see a modifications because the right scale changes to adapt to the dataset values, so thank you for that. However i still can't see my second line on the graph. Have you got any idea of why it is so ?

Comment: That is because you specify borderWidth as 0.0 so the line has a width of 0 so it wont show, same for your bar

Comment: Okay thanks. The 2 plots shows up but the line graph scale folllows the z axis scale so not really as expected. I will investigate and let you know

Comment: No it does not? If I put your code in a fiddle the right scale (z) goes from 0-18 while your line goes from 1-2 which is the left scale (y)

Comment: Can you send me the fiddle link ? must be a typo from me

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oqb6u9cs/